How do I set the defaultValue of shadcn ui Select component with dynamically generated SelectItem
I am trying to create an edit form that has the details of an already saved user details. I want the defaultvalue of the select component to be the name saved for the customer while the dynamically generated selectitems will be the other options should a user decide select a different customer from the drop down. Basically, instead of having the <SelectValue> placeholder on display, I want the default value to be on display.
const expense = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.expenseSlice.expense);
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState({
    merchantName: `${expense._id}`,
    expenseId: expense.expenseId,
    amount: expense.amount,
    tax: expense.tax,
    date: new Date(expense.date),
    expenseDescription: expense.expenseDescription,
  });
const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      merchant: formValue.merchantName,
      expenseNumber: formValue.expenseId,
      amount: formValue.amount,
      tax: formValue.tax,
      date: formValue.date,
      expenseDescription: formValue.expenseDescription,
    },
  });

<Select
    defaultValue={field.value}
    onValueChange={field.onChange}
    >
      <FormControl className="">
         <SelectTrigger id="merchant">
             <SelectValue />
         </SelectTrigger>
      </FormControl>
      <SelectContent>
         <div>
            <SelectGroup>
               <ScrollArea className="h-50 mt-3 ">
                  <div>
                     {!data ? (<Loader />) : (showFilter.map((merchant) => (
                        <div key={merchant.id} className="">
                           <SelectItem
                              value={merchant.id}>
                                 {merchant.name}
                            </SelectItem>
                            <SelectSeparator/>
                         </div>
                          )))}
                  </div>
                </ScrollArea>
             </SelectGroup>
                            

I retrieved the expense from the redux state and the set the default values for the respective fields which work for others apart from the Select. The SelectTrigger does not display anything. But when another value is selected, it displays the selected value. However it fails to display the default value before a user tried to edit or change this value.
